# Rolling row filter/crosstab in pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a highly sparse dataframe (only one non-zero value per row) indexed by  non-regular Timestamps for which I am trying to do the following.

For each non-zero value in a given column, I want to count the numbers of other non-zero values in other columns within a given timedelta. In a way, I am trying to compute something similar to a **rolling** cross_tab.

My solution so far is ugly and slow as I haven't figured out how to do this using slicing and rolling. It looks something like:

```
delta = 1
values = pd.DataFrame(0,index= df.columns,columns= df.columns)
for j in df.columns:
    for i in range(len(df[df[j]!=0].index)-1):
        #min is used to avoid overlapping
        values[j] +=df[(df.index<min((df[df[j]!=0].index + pd.tseries.timedeltas.to_timedelta(delta, unit='h'))[i],df[df[j]!=0].index[i+1]))&(df.index>=df[df[j]!=0].index[i])].astype(bool).sum()
values = values.T
```

and a toy-example dataframe is:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"2016-01-01 10:00.00":[0,1],
                         "2016-01-01 10:30.00":[1,0],
                         "2016-01-01 12:00.00":[0,1],
                         "2016-01-01 14:00.00":[1,0]},
                        orient="index")
 df.columns=['a','b']
 df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

                      a  b
 2016-01-01 10:00:00  0  1
 2016-01-01 10:30:00  1  0
 2016-01-01 12:00:00  0  1
 2016-01-01 14:00:00  1  0
```

The desired output should look like (with the counts depending on the timedelta):

```
      a     b
a     1     0
b     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what exactly you want.  But it sounded kind of like this

I want to use a new feature pandas `0.19`.  Time aware `rolling`.  In order to use it, we need a sorted index.

```
d1 = df.sort_index()
```

Now, let's assume we want to count within plus or minus one hour.  Let's start by adding two hours to every element of the index

```
d1.index = d1.index + pd.offsets.Hour(2)
```

Then we'll roll through, looking back four hours.  This will be like looking forward two hours and backwards two hours relative to the original indices.

```
d2 = d1.rolling('4H').sum()
d2.index = d2.index - pd.offsets.Hour(2)
d2

                       a    b
2016-01-01 10:00:00  0.0  1.0
2016-01-01 10:30:00  1.0  1.0
2016-01-01 12:00:00  1.0  2.0
2016-01-01 14:00:00  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: The timestamps are sorted (which I should have mentioned).

This is slightly different to what I want it seems. I'll try to clarify a bit.
I want to count the number of changes in column b ocuring within one hour of a change in a
In my example, a changes once within one hour of a b change -> counted in the output in row b column a (the diagonal is just the number of value changes for each column in the original dataframe). 

Your answer is just a rolling sum of the values of one column if I understand correctly.